# Can't connect to the internet

Tags: wireless, networking

I am able to connect to my wireless connection without any problems, but when I open Firefox it says "server not found". I am running Ubuntu 12.10 trough live usb on my Acer Aspire One netbook.

Pinging my router works fine. I have also changed    servername to     8.8.8.8. Pinging it doesn't work. It just says    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. When I cancel the operation I get the following "170 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packed loss, time 168999ms"

Any solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In my opinion you should reset router settings.

Comment: Does your router work for other connections? Like, other computers on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in a comment; you should try to reset your router settings in order to make it work.

When you are connected to the router, it doesnt mean that the router allows you to go past it. So, it isn't for sure that you are on the world wide web only by connecting to router? So, firefox tells you that he tried to connect to the internet, and he failed because he didn't find any "servers" to connect to. If you ain't sure what you are configuring, don't configure it without having support or help from someone who does know what to do.